# Counting Heads and Tails in a coin flip program

Tags: python

For my assignment, I have to use Functions within Python to simulate a coin flip. I managed to get the coin flip to showcase heads and tales for the amount the user has inputted. However, for the next portion, I have to get the program to read how many times Heads and Tails appeared. The error I am getting is

> 'NameError: name 'heads' is not defined'.

```
import random

def main():
    
    tosses = int(input("Please enter the amount of coin tosses:"))
    coin(tosses)
    count = 0
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    

def coin(tosses):
    for toss in range(tosses):

        if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
            print('Heads')
            heads += 1
            count += 1
        else:
            print('Tails')
            heads += 1
            count += 1


print (heads)
print (tails)
            
main()
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: You should elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Rather than give the answer, it might be better to show what you've already tried. For instance do you have some python code to simulate the flipping of a coin?

Comment: your answer should be somewhere close to 1 / (1/2)**10 tries

Comment: Apologies, I fixed the description and added the link to the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

`heads` was defined out of the scope of the function `coin`.

## Solution

Try defining the variables inside the function, then returning them. *Note: the same had to be done with `main`.*

```py
import random

def main():
    
    tosses = int(input("Please enter the amount of coin tosses:"))
    coin(tosses)
    heads, tails, count = coin(tosses)
    return heads, tails
    

def coin(tosses):
    count = 0
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for toss in range(tosses):

        if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
            print('Heads')
            heads += 1
            count += 1
        else:
            print('Tails')
            tails += 1  # note you had this say heads before
            count += 1
    return heads, tails, count
            
heads, tails = main()
print(heads)
print(tails)
```

## More on why this problem occurred

- When you use `def` and create a new function, all of the variables in that function are accessible *just to that function*.
- What was happening to you, is that you were trying to update the `heads` variable with `heads += 1`, but the function literally didn't know what the variable you were referring to is! (That variable was defined in `main`, and is only accessible from within the `main` function.)

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate that a little? I've only started Python 5 days ago as part of a short module and I'm still confused on Functions within Python.

Comment: Just added a bit more info. Try googling/searching youtube for more info on **scope** in Python, it is a very important concept to Python and I recommend you spend a little bit of time exploring how it works. I hope this helps you!